# .htaccess передать путь к файлу

Tags: .htaccess, php

Сейчас при переходе на сайт по ссылки http://site.ru/blog/129560.html в фаил index.php передается переменная "q" равная "blog/129560.html". 
Как сделать чтобы "дерево" сайта передавалась в разные параметры, т.е. к примеру: 
http://site.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560.html
q[0] = company; q[1] = sprinthost; q[2] = blog; q[3] = 129560.html;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Никак. .htaccess - скрипт обработки с базовыми возможностями, а не язык программирования. Разбирайте в скрипте PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно можно, только это будет неудобно, т.к. нужно будет продумать правила для любого кол-ва q, для трёх например:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php?q1=$1&q2=$2&q3=$3 [L, QSA]
```

Но намного **лучше** просто с помощью PHP разобрать:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q = explode('/', $q);
```

В итоге $q будет массивом, как раз таким, который вы хотели видеть

Comment: $q = $_GET['q'];
$q = explode('/', $q);
самое простое и нужное решение для автора.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Думал с помощью .htaccess будет проще и правильнее, не хотел сервер лишними действиями загружать. Сделаю на ПХП.